# ubuntu 13.10 with windows 7, 32 or 64 bits for 6gb of ram in AMD processor 32 bits

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit

My processor is an AMD 32-bit, but supports up to 8GB of RAM. 
I'm going to install ubuntu 13.10 alongside windows 7 with 6 gigs and I want to know if windows 32bit supports 6 gigs if ubuntu 13.10 32bit supports 6 gigs, 
if not possible and need to install 64-bit to use more gigs, I can install the versions of windows and ubuntu 64 bit on my 32-bit processor? 
please help. 
thanks in advance

Comment: I seriously doubt that you have a 32bit AMD processor. I don't think they've made one the last ten years or so and you'd have a very difficult time installing 8GB on those motherboards.

Answer (score 2):

No if your processor is 32bit you must use the 32bit operating system and applications on it. Windows will not support PAE so you will be limited to 4gb of accessible ram, but many versions of the linux kernel available in distro repos have PAE built in, and by default the Ubuntu 32bit kernel comes with PAE out of the box so you will have access to all 8gb while using the linux install so you should not be worried about that.